# Filtering a list based on another list

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I want to filter `data` based on items in `drop`.

```
data = [
    ['Basket', 'NBA ET', 'Kobe'],
    ['Basket', 'NCAA', 'Shaq'],
    ['Basket', 'ENG', 'Shaq'],
]
drop = ['NBA', 'NCAA']
```

And because I want the list with `NBA ET` to be left out too, it must be something beyond:

```
filtered = [d for d in data if d[1] not in drop]   # assume d[1] will hold
```

What I need is:

```
# pseudocode
filtered = [d for d in data if _ not in d[1] for _ in drop]
```

but I can never remember the syntax.

For the record, `filtered` should results in  `[['Basket', 'ENG', 'Shaq']]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`any()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) and split the string on whitespace:

```
filtered = [d for d in data if not any(dropped in d[1].split() for dropped in drop)]
```

If you make `drop` a *set*, just test for an intersection:

```
drop = set(drop)

filtered = [d for d in data if not drop.intersection(d[1].split())]
```

The latter should be more performant the larger `drop` becomes.

Demo:

```
>>> data = [
...     ['Basket', 'NBA ET', 'Kobe'],
...     ['Basket', 'NCAA', 'Shaq'],
...     ['Basket', 'ENG', 'Shaq'],
... ]
>>> drop = ['NBA', 'NCAA']
>>> [d for d in data if not any(dropped in d[1].split() for dropped in drop)]
[['Basket', 'ENG', 'Shaq']]
>>> drop = set(drop)
>>> [d for d in data if not drop.intersection(d[1].split())]
[['Basket', 'ENG', 'Shaq']]
```

Comment: @nutship: ick, yes, you want to *remove* not include. Corrected.

Comment: @nutship: I wasn't downvoted; someone removed their upvote instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
[row for row in data if not any(league in row[1].split() for league in drop)]
# [['Basket', 'ENG', 'Shaq']]
```

Comment: There is no need to create a list for `any()`. In fact, that defeats the purpose of using `any()` in the first place. Don't use a list comprehension here, use a generator expression instead (drop the `[...]` brackets from the `any()` call).

Comment: Strange, when I remove the list comprehension, the result is empty. What is the reason for this?

Comment: No, your code works for me. Your code is identical to mine without the `[..]` (save for the names used).

Comment: I'm on python 2.7, could that be the reason?

Comment: No, I use Python 2.7 too.

Comment: For the record, I meant your code should be `[row for row in data if not any(league in row[1].split() for league in drop)]`.